# Illegal characters in POST parameters

Tags: php, html, http-post

Are there any illegal characters in values sent by POST method?

I know that lots of characters are illegal in GET parameters, e.g. &, =, as they are used as delimiters etc.
Is it the same with parameters sent by POST method, e.g. by the following form?

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="parameter1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No. There is nothing wrong with your form, It should work for both POST and GET. GET has it's limitation since the data are passed in the URL, which you can counter by properly url encode it. POST isn't sent in the URL and is there fore not constricted by the same limitations. Are you asking because of an issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering whether using some characters in forms sent by post can trigger some kind of error.

Comment: No, there's not characters that can trigger any errors in a pure POST. If an error occurs, it because of improper handling on the receiving end, depending on what you do with the data.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I won't worry about illegal characters any more.

Comment: Do worry - not every post is handled under the hood for you. I was working with a system where the user could POST a message to a database. Some users might want to include an ampersand, an equal sign, or a comma. In those casses, I had to use a built in Android function that would make the string "Safe" for posting that did someting similar to Silinator's code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
   function normtext($input,$db_link){
        $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link,$input); //optional

        $illegal = array(
            '&' => '&amp;',
            '=' => '&equals;',
            '<' => '&lt;',
            '>' => '&gt;',
            "'" => '&#096;'
            //...and many more

        );
        $output = str_replace(array_keys($illegal),
            array_values($illegal), $input);

        return $output;
   }
```

Comment: Ok, I can use it, but is it necessary? The character "&" used in a form sent by POST method does not trigger error.

Comment: oh. You're right I think. Ok then do it in [-and-] and make it when receiving in the device

Comment: This is utterly useless. Why would you manually escape post data like this when you don't even know what it's gonna be used for? (and the mysqli_real_escape_string() would fail in this context since you 1. need an active DB connection and $db_link would be undefined). You escape data depending on the usage (what you're gonna do with it). And for DB, you should use Prepared Statements, which removes the need for escaping data.

Comment: @ MagnusEriksson Meh. It makes perhaps as yet no sense. But I think he will work with a DB after that. And then you should absolutely use mysqli_real_escape_string ()!
And $ db_link must of course be sent along. (I adjusted).

But in this case it brings nothing.

Comment: @Silinator - If the data is going to be used for any database actions, he should use PDO (since we don't even know what engine will be used) and Prepared Statements, which is _by far_ the best protection for SQL injections, and _not_ mysqli_real_escape_string (which only works for MySQL and MariaDB and should only be used for _strings_, not all data types like integers).

Comment: @Silinator Rule of thumb, don't escape data until you _need_ to and then escape it in a manner that fits the purpose. There is no "general" escaping that works for everything. You will most likely just mess up the data. Btw, you shouldn't parse HTML manually. Use built in functions like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead. Rolling your own escaping functions for these kind of things will mos likely end in disaster...

Answer (score -1):

**The first rule in web security : "Do not trust user"**

Both get & post user can put any thing in it and you must filter any input that user make it , in your form example the value in textfiled sent to server by post method and that don't make it safer than get method the difference between them that the textfiled value doesn't visible in url .

**Remember: you must filter all of user inputs in post & get.**

Comment: This did not answer their question at all. I know what their question is because I have it too ;)